# 20.04.04 libmysqlclient21 breaks wine

Tags: package-management, wine, mysql

Due to unknown reason the upgrading of `libmysqlclient21` from focal-proposed started to require to remove `libsnmp:386`,`libsane:386` and `wine-stable:386`, thus removing the entire wine installaion (wine, wine-stable(not 386), winetricks and so on).

I have no idea how to resolve this issue: I need `wine`, I need `sane`, I need `mysql client`.

U20.04.04, amd64

exact logs will be posted later, if needed

Comment: Do you need `proposed`? It always caused problems for me.

Comment: hmm... it seems to be logical. But I never got such problems before. The most funny part is that the orher components of musql were upgraded successfully

Comment: It seems like there is no libmysqlclient21:i386 package which is causing a cascade of breakages...

Comment: You can see here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/libmysqlclient21 that's there's no `libmysqlclient21 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.4` package for i386, not sure who to ask about that though...

Comment: I've e-mailed a developer, and will update if a new package gets built.

Comment: @labarna the lib version is amd64, but it requires to remove 386 files, that is what disturbs me

Comment: Yeah, if you dig into the details (via sometime like `aptitude`) you'll see that the i386 library is the sticking point.  Wine installs an i386 version by default so that's why it's suggesting a much larger removal. The Ubuntu developers said they'd re-run the build process to fix the libraries.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Instead press the checkmark next to the answer below if it helped you, or post your own answer and mark that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builds have been fixed and the missing package `libmysqlclient21_8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.4_i386.deb` is now available: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/i386/libmysqlclient21/8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.4

Comment: Thank you very much. I just disabled "proposed" repo, and that was sufficient. Will wait if package will arrive to "stable/ipdates/security"